# Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I have checked the solution for this issue and most of the answers are pointing at the .env file. This is mine and I'm not using homestead. Should I install it ? 
I'm using mysql database for my other project and it works fine.

```
 APP_ENV=local
 APP_KEY=base64:9pZJdb1+0u3kb+MQ+1WR9HYr5CunniuYLVWITTTckn4=
 APP_DEBUG=true
 APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
 APP_URL=http://localhost

 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_DATABASE=injaz
 DB_USERNAME=root
 DB_PASSWORD=123123

 BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
 CACHE_DRIVER=file
 SESSION_DRIVER=file
 QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

 REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
 REDIS_PASSWORD=null
 REDIS_PORT=6379

 MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
 MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
 MAIL_PORT=2525 
 MAIL_USERNAME=null
 MAIL_PASSWORD=null
 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

 PUSHER_APP_ID=
 PUSHER_KEY=
 PUSHER_SECRET=
```

Comment: try to restart server after changing .env file.

Comment: try to clear config cache, using command:     php artisan config:clear

Answer (score 2):

did you try to refresh your config cache ?

```
php artisan config:cache
```

then restart your server